# Error when console.log the displayname of the message owner

Tags: discord.js

I get this Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of null
```

This is the code that should console-log the command and the username of the user who used it:

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
        const { content, member } = message
        const autor = member.displayName || member.username

        aliases.forEach((alias) => {
            const command = `${prefix}${alias}`
            
            if (content.startsWith(`${command}`) || content === command) {
                console.log(`${autor} used: ${command}`)
                callback(message)
            }    
        })
    })
```

In the console I get the username but it still gives an error. It only gives this error if I use a specific command. The command sends an embed of the message. Then it sends a copy of the message to the user who sent it.

```
if (message.content.includes('...'))
        {message.delete({timeout: 800})
        .then(message.member.send(message.content))
        message.channel.send(embed)
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the nickname primarily, you can make your bot default to the username if the nickname is unavailable.

For your first section, you can use a [ternary operator.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
const autor = member ? member.displayName : message.author.username
```

If `member` returns null, it'll instead use the `username` property of the `author` which is never null.

For the second part of your code, you might as well replace `message.member.send()` with `message.author.send()` since then former provides no advantages over the latter and instead only leads to instances such as this one.

Comment: That worked. Again something new i need to learn. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

As from [the documentation about `message.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member):

> Represents the author of the message as a guild member. Only available if the message comes from a guild where the author is still a member

That means the error you are having may happen if the user is not a member of the server/guild anymore, or is a private message.

You can use `message.author` if you just want the username. Or you can return the function when `message.member` is null.

Comment: I am still working on the bot, so it is me who sends the message. `message.author` does not display the displayName / Nickname of the user. I think it is related to the message it sends to the user. Maybe it has problems with finding the guild the member is in. And it still gives an error even if it shows the right displayName.